# Invoking method using AST passing default arguments

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I want to invoke a method using eclipse AST.
I have the `MethodDeclarion` of the method to be invoked. How can I invoke this method passing appropriate DUMMY/ default arguments.

i.e.

```
public void setStr (String str) { ... };
public void setSomeObj (SomeObj obj ) { ... };
```

Suppose I have `MethodDeclarion`s of the above methods.

Now I want to create a `MethodInvocation` like the following.

```
setStr("some dummy value");
setSomeObj(new SomeObj());
```

The difficulty I have is generating the DUMMY/ default arguments for method invocation.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MethodInvocation s;
s.arguments().add(...);
```

if you want to add an object that is part of the existing AST it needs to be:

```
....add((Cast)r.createCopyTarget(Object));
```

Cast = you will probaby have to cast it to a certain type, eclipse will tell you which.